# How to handle exception resulting in unresolved promise

Tags: javascript, exception, callback, promise, es6-promise

I'm seeing some inconsistent behaviour when dealing with a promise that fails to resolve due to an unforeseen uncaught exception. It seems that depending on how I chain the promise changes whether this promise resolves and I don't understand why.

Here is the bad function:

```
function bad() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      throw 'unforseen exception!';
      resolve();
    }, 50);
  });
}
```

If I call this function these ways it does not resolve:

```
bad().then(() => console.log('resolved')); // no console logging

try {
  await bad();
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
console.log('resolved'); // no console logging
```

But calling it like this does resolve:

```
Promise.resolve().then(bad()).then(() => console.log('resolved')); // console logs "resolved"
```

<strike>Why is this?</strike> Edit: I now understand what I was doing wrong. But what I really want to answer is the next part.

And how do I best protect myself against unforeseen exceptions when I have a chain of promises that need to be run serially and need to continue even if there is a failure somewhere along the chain?

I have also tried using catch or finally but they don't seem to make any difference. Once that unresolved promise is reached, execution fails.

Comment: one issue is with `.then(bad())` ... `.then` argument is a *function*, not, as you are doing, *the result of calling a function* - you *should* be doing `.then(bad)` instead -

Comment: @Jaromanda X I did not really see one as more correct. I was just confused as to why one behaved differently . Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: yeah, I removed that part of the comment - that's not the only issue, but it is why the code behaves differently for the last code fragment

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `bad()` throws an error *asynchronously* in such a way that the error can't be detected by the caller. If you want to throw an error inside a `new Promise...` segment, you should call the `reject` function:

```js
function bad() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject('bad!');
      resolve();
    }, 50);
  });
}


bad()
  .then(() => console.log('resolved'))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

(async () => {
  try {
    await bad();
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  console.log('await finished');
})();
```

The reason your

```
Promise.resolve().then(bad()).then
```

calls the next `.then` is because `then` accepts a *function* as a parameter, but your `bad()` is *invoking `bad` in the beginning*, while the interpreter is trying to come up with the Promise chain. If you had passed `bad` as the function parameter instead of calling it, you would see similar broken behavior as in your original code - the `Promise` would never resolve:

```js
function bad() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      throw 'unforseen exception!';
      resolve();
    }, 50);
  });
}

// Promise never resolves:
Promise.resolve().then(bad).then(() => console.log('resolved'));
```

In contrast, `.then(bad())` will evaluate to a non-function, and hence that `.then` will resolve *immediately*, so the interpreter will go on to the next `.then` immediately as well.

Comment: For the first part, the idea was that it's an "unforeseen" exception. I've only explicitly thrown it here for clarity, but in reality it's a deeper exception that is not being handled properly. In my case, it was breaking the init portion of my application. What I really want to know is, how do I protect myself against this happening again? It seems that there is no way? Assuming I need my promises to run in serial.

Comment: You *should* have a general idea of on which lines exceptions might be thrown while writing a script - you can `catch` them and then call `reject`.

Comment: In this case, it was a cross origin exception within an html image.onload function. And it only became an issue after a new chrome release. Not obvious in this case (seeing as the image src was local). And it has led me to wonder about other potential issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    throw 'unforseen exception!';
    resolve();
  }, 50);
});
```

The throw is happening in a non-async callback function. The way to handle something like this would be to use a try/catch statement on the code that could throw:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    try {
      throw 'unforseen exception!';

      resolve();
    }
    catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  }, 50);
});
```

Comment: I agree. This does seem the best way to go. But how do I apply this in practise when I don't know which parts of my code are likely to throw errors in the future? Should I be wrapping every callback within a promise inside a try catch to ensure that they resolve?

In this instance, it was a cross origin exception within an html image.onload function. And it only became an issue after a new chrome release. Not obvious (seeing as the image src was local).

Do I need to check the source of every external function I call to make sure I'm handling all possible exceptions?

Comment: @DeaconMeek Ideally you should be able to know if a function call will throw an error by checking the documentation. Wrapping the whole callback in a try/catch is also possible if that's not possible for some reason.

Comment: I would answer this as accepted, except that it doesn't mention anything about my mistake of invoking the bad() function inside of a promise.then. I believe the correct solution lies between yours and that of @CertainPerformance